# How can I repair my O2 Generator in an oxygen deprived ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If my ship has 0% oxygen in it, how can I repair my O<sub>2</sub> generator if my crew wont live long enough to do so?

Note that I've already tried, and because of this I have 2 crew members stuck in my medbay holding even at 10% health each.

Comment: If you still have *some* oxygen left, you can open a few (carefully chosen) doors to allow it to flow into other rooms.

Comment: Is anyone else freaked out by the idea of a "medbay" keeping your barely alive but in a perpetual state of asphyxiation?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I upgrade my medbay, it will heal my crew faster than the O<sub>2</sub> depletion hurts them, allowing me to take 2 crew members and send them to the O<sub>2</sub> generator and repair it fast enough to get back to the medbay and safety while my ship equalizes pressure.

Edit Advanced Edition: It's also worth noting that if you have Engi-Med Bot Dispersal and Emergency-Respirators you can last a HECK OF A LONG TIME in full vacuum.

Comment: What happens if you upgrade a broken O2 system? Can you put some power in it?

Comment: I tried this once, upgrading a broken system results in the new level being broken as well.

Comment: Which is a good reason to upgrade O2 early (even if you don't power it).

Comment: Note that if for some reason the 2 crew members couldn't repair the room quickly enough (maybe they're mantis?), having them switch off would also work, so long as there's always someone in the oxygen room.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to get into this sort of situation, repair bots are very useful as they don't require any oxygen. Similarly, in the Advanced Edition, you can also use repair bombs.

Another (more desperate) approach - **acquire more crew!**

If your engines are still online and fully charged, and you can get a crew member to the helm for long enough to click on Jump, and there happens to be a store in an adjacent system, you might be able to purchase a crew member, who'll join your ship at full health and may be able to repair your Oxygen system before asphyxiating.

Even if there isn't a store within range, it's possible that there's a 'free crew' event - (Advanced Edition - even better if you're in an abandoned sector and the new crew member happens to be Lanius). If you have the necessary scrap, see if you can upgrade any of your systems that would qualify for relevant blue options.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend jumping unless its an absolute last resort though.  Chances are high you'll run into hostiles instead.